# Movement on grid creating duplication to the left randomly

Tags: java

I'm new to java and have been working on a small ecosystem project. The main grid for the entire game is represented by a 2d array called grid[][]. The list of organisms is population[][]. For simplicity I have only been using one organism for testing.

I am working on the movement which works as follows:

1. Change the tile on the grid in the position of the organism to the tile under the organism
2. Change the organism's position
3. Record the tile under the organism
4. Replace the tile with the organism's id

When moving, sometimes the organism makes duplicates of itself that only appear in that tick and are gone the next. I have been looking hard for 2 days and can't find why they do this.

Here's the important code:

```
package ecosystem.Window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    public boolean running=false;
    public int fps;
    public Thread thread;
    public Random rand=new Random();
    public int tile=33;

    public final int WATER=-2;
    public final int TREES=-1;
    public final int GROUND=0;
    public final int PREY=1;
    public final int PREDATOR=2;

    public final int X=0;
    public final int Y=1;
    public final int UNDERSQUARE=2;

    public int[][]grid=new int[16][16];
    public int[][]population=new int[10][3];
    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
        return;

        running=true;
        thread=new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Window(640,480,"Ecosystem",new Game());

    }
    public void init(){
        int row=0;
        int column=0;
        int r;
        while(row<15){
            if(column>=15){
                row+=1;
                column=0;
            }else{
                column+=1;
            }
            r=rand.nextInt(4);
            grid[column][row]=(r-3);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            population[i][X]=rand.nextInt(16);
            population[i][Y]=rand.nextInt(16);
            population[i][UNDERSQUARE]=GROUND;
            grid[population[i][X]][population[i][Y]]=PREY;
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        init();
        this.requestFocus();
        System.out.println(" ");

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 10000000000.0;
        int frames=0;
        double ns = 8000000000000000000.0 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;

                render();
            }

            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                fps=frames;
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    private void tick() {
        System.out.println("Tick");

        grid[population[1][X]][population[1][Y]]=population[1][UNDERSQUARE];
        population[1][X]--;
        population[1][UNDERSQUARE]=grid[population[1][X]][population[1][Y]];

        grid[population[1][X]][population[1][Y]]=PREY;
    }

    private void render() {
        int column=0;
        int row=0;
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 900);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 494, 496);
        //GRID//
        while(row<15){
            if(column>=15){
                row+=1;
                column=0;
            }else{
                column+=1;
            }
            if(grid[column][row]==WATER){
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
            }
            if(grid[column][row]==TREES){
                g.setColor(Color.green);
            }
            if(grid[column][row]==GROUND){
                g.setColor(Color.orange);
            }
            if(grid[column][row]==PREY){
                g.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            if(grid[column][row]==PREDATOR){
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            g.fillRect(column*tile-(tile+1), row*tile, (tile-1), (tile-1));

        }
        //CONTROL PANEL//


        /////////////////

        /////////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
        //System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing AWT objects directly from another thread (e.g. by calling `render()` from your thread, or any other `Canvas` methods of `this`). You can only access these objects from the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). If you don't, all bets are off; and this can easily corrupt your rendered output. The linked description of the EDT has this to say about it:

> Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.

You will need to make some changes. You have a couple of options.

The easiest option is probably to use [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from your thread, with a `Runnable` that calls `render()`. You could use `invokeLater()` but then you'd have to take special care to make sure that you are synchronizing access to data. Still, you'll also have to go through your code and make sure you aren't calling *any* of the `Canvas` methods from your other thread (e.g. `this.requestFocus()` is a no-go).

Other options include redesigning your code so that the GUI is rendering on its own, e.g. through a timer, and actively querying the current state from your thread; instead of having your thread control the rendering, have the GUI pull the state from the thread. This can become complicated sometimes, especially when you want a 1:1 correspondence between simulation frames and GUI updates.

In general, having your class extend `Canvas` but also having your thread implementation there is a bad combination; since none of the `Canvas` methods in general can be safely called from another thread. You should consider decoupling your simulation logic from your GUI (i.e. don't put your game logic in a `Canvas`); this will have many other potential benefits as well.